# Specify separate sources for different packages in pyproject.toml

Tags: python, dependency-management, python-poetry, pyproject.toml

My project has various private python packages developed internally in my organization. I am using `[tool.poetry.source]` to specify the PyPi server. I have a use case to specify custom PyPi server url for different packages. This is the content of my `pyproject.toml`

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.8"
package-a = "0.1.2"
package-b = "0.2.1"
package-c = "0.4.2"

[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "internal-repo-1"
url = "https://<private-repo-1>"

[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "internal-repo-2"
url = "https://<private-repo-2>"
```

I want to use `private-repo-1` from `package-a` and `private-repo-2` for `package-b` and `package-c`. How can this be achieved ? Also can this be achieved without scanning all the private repositories for each and every package? I am using poetry for dependency management.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is described in the [docs](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#dependencies-and-dependency-groups):

```ini
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.8"
package-a = { version = "0.1.2", source = "internal-repo-1" }
package-b = { version = "0.2.1", source = "internal-repo-2" }
package-c = { version = "0.4.2", source = "internal-repo-2" }

[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "internal-repo-1"
url = "https://<private-repo-1>"

[[tool.poetry.source]]
name = "internal-repo-2"
url = "https://<private-repo-2>"
```

Comment: Iis it possible to have two sources for the same package ? Like the way pip uses `-index-url` and `--extra-index-url` ?